# Is it possible to combine two different proof technique?

Tags: proof-writing

When I'm proving some problems, am I allowed to use two different proof technique to prove a problem?

For instance, let's say I decided to do proof by contradiction on certain algorithm. Since algorithm has a pattern, I am thinking of using induction as well within contradiction proof.

So it would look like following:

```
      Proof by contradiction

      Prove base case of induction is false

      Prove inductive step of induction is false.
```

Comment: You mean, you want assume something, and using proof by induction arrive to contradiction and so conclude that your assumption was false ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Yes, basically I want to assume that problem is false (contradiction) and then use induction to prove that my assumption is false.

Comment: @selfPointer Then yes, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can combine several different proof techniques within a larger proof.

But the way you do combine a prof by contradiction with a proof by induction makes little sense.

Say that you want to prove that $P(n)$ for all $n$. Induction would seem to be a good option, so you could try and prove the base and step, possibly using a proof by contradiction for each or both. So sure, using a proof by contradiction within the parts of a proof by induction could certainly make sense.

But you are doing something quite different. You are doing a proof by contradiction on the whole thing. But that means you have to show that if we do *not* have $P(n)$ for all $n$, i.e. that if there is *some* $n$ for which we do not have $P(n)$, then we get a contradiction.

But you certainly do *not* show that by showing that the base case for induction does not hold. So what if it does not hold? How is that a contradiction? Indeed, if it does not hold for the base case, then you certainly will *not* be able to prove that $P(n)$ for all $n$, since that is apparently false.

Similarly, if the step not hold, you have not established any kind of contradiction. All you have shown is that $P(n+1)$ does not follow from $P(n)$. So? Nothing really follows from that.  It doesn't even follow that it is false that $P(n)$ for all $n$: maybe $P(n+1)$ relies on $P(n-1)$ holding.

And showing that *both* the base and the step don't hold doesn't show any kind of contradiction either. Again, all it shows is that what you're trying to show is false, rather than true.